# Assign positive and negative button a dialogfragment with custom view and buttons

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am using a dialog fragment with a custom view. It has a tick mark below. I want to assign the tick as the "postive button".

`setPositiveButton` takes string in the common way.

```
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    getDialog().dismiss();
                }
            }
    );
```

[image]

Comment: is that a spinner..?

Comment: no it is custom view called wheelview

Comment: does it take array list..?

Comment: yes...here's the library: https://github.com/venshine/WheelView

Comment: Is it mandatory to use DialogInterface, or you can create a custom dialog?

Comment: custom dialog would do...I was wondering whether this is possible with the interface